# Bibtex's formal format for citation key field

Tags: bibtex, bibtool

I have seen multiple posts what "nice" formats one might use for bibtex citation keys as in

```
@ARTICLE{ FormatInQuestion,
   author = {XXX},
    title = {YYY},
}
```

My question is different, and arises when doing

```
bibtool --preserve.key.case=on --preserve.keys=on refs.bib > refs_new.bib
```

where I get

```
@article{ doi:10.1016/s0012-365x(97)00126-x,
_________________________________^
*** BibTool ERROR:  (line 2101 in ./references.bib): Unexpected character encountered
```

so even though I ask bibtool to not change the citations keys whatsoever, it complains about having an opening parenthesis `(` in the key.

My question is

**What format is formally allowed to be used for the citation key "FormatInQuestion"?**

As an example, I expect that only a closing parenthesis `FormatInQuestion` = `}` is probably not allowed. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think there are illegal characters for the key, except for (unbalanced) braces, `%` and backslash. I guess that BibTool is adding some checks on its own.

Comment: Once more thanks for your quick responce! So `@ARTICLE{{}(97), author = {XXX}, title = {YYY} }` with key `{}(97)` is an acceptable format? Do you happen to have any reference to some documentation specifying this?

Comment: I'm not *sure* what the legal characters are. I tried looking in the standard sources and found nothing. Oh, obviously the comma!

Comment: So, any idea how to make bibtool completely ignoring citation keys?

Comment: Ask the author of BibTool. It's not even distributed in TeX Live, so I can't do experiments; I tried to compile it on my machine, but the instructions are not helpful.

Comment: I managed to install `bibtool` and got a few surprises.

Answer (score 10):

I've made a few experiments.

1. Braces are not allowed. If in initial position they're dropped by the LaTeX argument scanner, in middle position they cause BibTeX to fail

   ```
   Stuff after "}"---line 2 of file bibstump.aux
    : \citation{b{ra
    :               }ces}
   I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
   ```
2. A comma is obviously disallowed, being the field separator.
3. The backslash, even escaped, is not allowed because of obvious TeXnical issues.
4. The percent is not allowed for similar reasons.
5. Other characters might be dangerous in LaTeX contexts, like double punctuation when French `babel` is active or straight quotes for several `babel` languages.
6. The citation key should consist of printable ASCII characters (with the above mentioned exceptions).

The following `.bib` file

```
@article{quo"tes,
  author={A B},
  title={T},
  journal={J},
  year=2000,
}
@article{(paren),
  author={A B},
  title={T},
  journal={J},
  year=2000,
}
@article{o@th[;]er,
  author={A B},
  title={T},
  journal={J},
  year=2000,
}
```

in a non `babel` document produces the following `.bbl` file

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{quo"tes}
A~B.
\newblock T.
\newblock {\em J}, 2000.

\bibitem{(paren)}
A~B.
\newblock T.
\newblock {\em J}, 2000.

\bibitem{o@th[;]er}
A~B.
\newblock T.
\newblock {\em J}, 2000.

\end{thebibliography}
```

On the other hand, running `bibtool` on the `.bib` file with the same options as you have in the question produces

```
@article{quo"tes,
_____________^
*** BibTool ERROR:  (line 1 in ./bibstump.bib): Unexpected character encountered

*** BibTool WARNING: Skipping to next '@'

*** BibTool WARNING:  (line 7 in ./bibstump.bib): 49 non-space characters ignored.

@article{(paren),
________________^
*** BibTool ERROR:  (line 7 in ./bibstump.bib): Unexpected character encountered

*** BibTool WARNING: Skipping to next '@'

*** BibTool WARNING:  (line 13 in ./bibstump.bib): 46 non-space characters ignored.
```

So I conclude that the error raised by BibTool is a decision by the programmer (possibly induced by the usage of Perl for the string management).

Comment: Perhaps note that BibTeX(8) requires the _key_ to be 7-bit, even though other parts of the file can be 'passed through' as UTF-8 or whatever (if not processed by BibTeX).

Comment: @JosephWright I considered that as obvious, but I'll add it.

Comment: Don't think it is, as like I say you can use UTF-8 happily in the bulk of a file if there is no case-changing or whatever in the `.bst`.

Comment: Can you refer to an "official" source where the bibtex format is described? I am not sure what these observations are based on and where the official format is documented.

Comment: @SybillePeters You can consult “Tame the BeaST” on your system with `texdoc tamethebeast` or online at https://texdoc.org/index.html, which would point to https://texdoc.org/serve/tamethebeast/0

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I looked in https://texdoc.org/serve/tamethebeast/0 Unfortunately, this also does not seem to give the information what characters can be used for citation key aka internal_key, for example. When writing / evaluating / testing libraries for parsing bibtex etc. I am looking for a more formal description.

Comment: @SybillePeters Use alphanumeric characters and you're on the safe side.