# Keywords of references in .bib file

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago, keywords

Can  I not change the  keywords of  bibtex entries in my .bib files? For example "@article{stapp_public_1990", this  is  the  keyword. I want the keyword to be  a bit  more convenient  for  me as in  "stapp_Public Museum: A Review of the Literature_1990" while  citing  in text.

But  as  soon as I move to change the  keyword texmaker doesn't insert the reference.

Comment: you can't put spaces in the key IRCC.

Comment: More convenient? The point of a key is easily call a reference, with a code, that therefore must be unique, but preferably predictable, short,  easy to type and easy to remember. Its purpose is not be an abstract nor a 128 bit password. More than some like  "stapp2015"( or "stapp2015a" in case of coincident keys) is ask for troubles, even using valid keys.  The longer the keys, the longer the number of mistakes.

Comment: Spaces (like a few other characters https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/581901/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408530/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243729/35864) are indeed forbidden in entry keys. You cannot use them. Normally, people try to make their entry keys as short yet as precise as possible. Putting the full title with spaces and all doesn't appear to be the best way forward to me. Note that the entry keys are internal: A reader will get to see the real citation provided everything is compiled correctly.