# Official bibtex format formal description?

Tags: bibtex

Is there a formal description for the bibtex format one can use for writing tests, evaluating libraries, writing libraries etc? For these the description needs to be very clear and definitive, what characters are allowed etc. So far, I have not found an official, formal description of the bibtex format.

I assume this is the official website:

- https://tug.org/bibtex/

In a comment, I got the tip to search on https://texdoc.org/index.html

Searching for "bibtex format" has no results.

Examples:

- In bibtex files (.bib), what are allowed characters in the citation key? See also [Bibtex's formal format for citation key field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335298/bibtexs-formal-format-for-citation-key-field)
- Is the citation key optional or must it exist?

I have seen entries like this, supposedly created by Citavi:

`@misc{RohlJHHellmersSDiekmannRHeinA(2022):.2022,`

`@BOOK{,`

Comment: For such an old tool I don't think it's too carefully thought out, so I suspect all you have is the source code of the script itself and whatever it accepts. (you may be able to extract a "commonly used" subset that can be formally described though)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks. I have also been looking through some of the available libraries and tools and one of them wrote the same thing (also refers to source code). Not sure where the original source code is though for bibtex, is that part of the tex suite? Anyhow, any answer which sheds some light on this would be welcome from my point of view.